# How can I redefine a starred LaTeX command that take parameters?

Tags: latex, renewcommand

I am trying to redefine `\chapter` command like this

```
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand\chapter[1]{{\color{green!30!blue!80}\oldchapter{#1}}}
```

These instructions were working before I start using the starred version `\chapter*`, but now I get compilation errors. I have searched a lot and found some guides ([like this one](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-cmdstar.html)) and answers but I can't get my code to work. Please tell me how I can edit this code to make it work, I have seen a lot of examples but I couldn't figure the right way to redefine starred commands.

Comment: See [Defining starred versions of commands (* macro)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4386/5764)

Comment: This is an XY-problem. Your real question is: How can i have a coloure chapter title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution from [this old topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/cRdZVGKvvdE). My working code is now :

```
\newcommand{\@chapterstar}[1]{{\color{green!30!blue!80}\oldchapter*{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@chapternostar}[1]{{\color{green!30!blue!80}\oldchapter{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\@ifstar{\@chapterstar}{\@chapternostar}}
```